# Difference between char* and wchar_t*

Tags: c++, c, string

I am new to MFC. I am trying to do simple mfc application and I'm getting confuse in some places. For example, `SetWindowText` have two api, `SetWindowTextA`, `SetWindowTextW` one api takes `char *` and another one accepts `wchar_t *`.

What is the use of `char *` and `wchar_t *`?

Comment: [Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dax2h36.aspx).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`char` is used for so called ANSI family of functions (typically function name ends with `A`), or more commonly known as using ASCII character set.

`wchar_t` is used for new so called Unicode (or Wide) family of functions (typically function name ends with `W`), which use UTF-16 character set. It is very similar to UCS-2, but not quite it. If character requires more than 2 bytes, it will be converted into 2 composite codepoints, and this can be very confusing.

If you want to convert one to another, it is not really simple task. You will need to use something like [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar), which requires knowing and providing code page for input ANSI string.

Comment: You've edited it, but you're missing the point: encoding a single character as two composite code units is the defining difference between UTF-16 and UCS-2.  In UTF-16, you can have four-byte characters that are encoded in two halves.  In UCS-2, that is not allowed, and **all** UCS-2 characters are two bytes.

Comment: More nitpicking: `wchar_t` is not used for UTF-16 on all compilers. It contains "some" unicode value, and range of this value on platform. On windows compilers wchar_t is normally 2bytes big and therefore contains UTF-16. However, on linux compiler it can easily be 4 bytes big.

Comment: **Windows** historically used `wchar_t` as UCS-2, but once the Unicode standard (and UTF-16) became a thing, it switched to treating `wchar_t` as UTF-16. Most of the important ‘W‘ functions treat `wchar_t` properly as UTF-16, but I believe there still exist some that do not.

Comment: **Linux** has historically been all over the place with `wchar_t`, but all modern implementations I am aware of treat `wchar_t` as UTF-32.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, APIs that take `char *` use the current code page whereas `wchar_t *` APIs use UTF-16.  As a result, you should **always** use `wchar_t` on Windows.  A recommended way to do this is to:

```
// Be sure to define this BEFORE including <windows.h>
#define UNICODE 1
#include <windows.h>
```

When `UNICODE` is defined, APIs like `SetWindowText` will be aliased to `SetWindowTextW` and can therefore be used safely.  Without `UNICODE`, `SetWindowText` will be aliased to `SetWindowTextA` and therefore cannot be used without first converting to the current code page.

However, there's no good reason to use `wchar_t` when you are not calling Windows APIs, since its portable functionality is not useful, and its useful functionality is not portable (`wchar_t` is UTF-16 only on Windows, on most other platforms it is UTF-32, what a total mess.)

Comment: Actually, instead of defining UNICODE, you might as well directly call the *W functions, then there's no chance of some file not defining UNICODE by accident.

Comment: Surely using TCHAR is a better way to go, this way if for whatever reason you do need an ANSI compiled version it is still possible, and it also works with the compiler setting `SetWindowText` to `SetWindowTextW` or `SetWindowTextA`

Comment: @Luke: There is **no valid reason** to write new code that does not support Unicode.  Avoid `TCHAR`.  (Okay, there's maybe a valid reason 0.001% of the time, but that doesn't apply to you.)

Comment: @Luke: If you use ANSI code pages then you won't be able to open files with filenames that contain characters outside your code page.  That can be a huge problem.  Also, your program will display paths incorrectly on certain systems: Install path `C:¥Program Files¥Company Name¥My Application`... something look wrong with that picture?  It's because you used ANSI instead of Unicode, and the computer has a Japanese locale.  **Don't use ANSI.**

Comment: Is it possible in future the standard adds a different character encoded variable and Microsoft make it possible for TCHAR to be compiled to that? Using TCHAR is equivalent to using `wchar_t` yet also has the added benefit of also being `char` and potentially whatever it is in future.

Answer (score 1):

`SetWindowTextA` takes *char**, which is a pointer to ANSI strings. 
`SetWindowTextW` takes *wchar_t**, which is a pointer to "wide" strings (Unicode).

`SetWindowText` has been defined (#define) to either of these in header `Windows.h` based on the type of application you are building. If you are building a UNICODE build then your code will automatically use `SetWindowTextW`.

`SetWindowTextA` is there primarily to support legacy code, which needs to be built as SBCS (Single byte character set).

Answer (score -4):

char*   :   It means that this is a pointer to data of type char.

Example

```
// Regular char
char aChar = 'a';

// Pointer to char
char* aPointer = new char;
*aPointer = 'a';

// Pointer to an array of 10 chars
char* anArray = new char[ 10 ];
*anArray = 'a';
anArray[ 1 ] = 'b';

// Also a pointer to an array of 10
char[] anArray = new char[ 10 ];
*anArray = 'a';
anArray[ 1 ] = 'b';
```

wchar_t*    :  wchar_t is defined such that any locale's char encoding can be converted to a wchar_t representation where every wchar_t represents exactly one codepoint.