# Show current time on output window in Visual Studio 2013 using C

Tags: c

I am trying to display current time on output window of Visual Studio. I need it for debugging purpose. Since printf() output doesn't print to output window of Visual Studio, i need to use OutputDebugString().

Code compiles correctly but output doesn't come out correctly. Can someone help me out here ? Thanks !

```
char buff[100];
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

sprintf(buff, "[%d %d %d %d:%d:%d]", timeinfo->tm_mday, timeinfo->tm_mon + 1, timeinfo->tm_year + 1900, timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min, timeinfo->tm_sec);
OutputDebugString(LPCWSTR(buff));
```

OUTPUT Window of Visual Studio prints :

```
?‹???????]
```

Expected: Date and time is printed correctly.

Comment: Try `OutputDebugStringA` instead of `OutputDebugString` and report here if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks ... it works..

Answer (score 0):

I know, the comment from Michael has already solved your problem. But, you should know the cause of problem to avoid making the same mistake again in future. So, this answer summarizes that.

First of all, some basics::
`A` and `W` in `OutputDebugStringA` & `OutputDebugStringW`, respectively stands for `Ansi` and `Wide characters`.

`Ansi` chars take upto 1 byte of memory like `char` and `Wide` chars take 2 bytes of memory like `wchar_t`.

For more reference, you can look here:: [Difference between char* and wchar_t*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532785/difference-between-char-and-wchar-t)

Now, when you have already defined `buff` as `char`, then why are you type-casting it to `LPCWSTR`. For more reference on `LPCWSTR`, see this:: [What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with)

So, basically, you should be calling `OutputDebugStringA(buff)`.

Another solution is, define `buff` as wide char array,

```
wchar_t buff[100];
wsprintf(buff, L"[%d %d %d %d:%d:%d]", timeinfo->tm_mday, 
     timeinfo->tm_mon + 1, timeinfo->tm_year + 1900, timeinfo->tm_hour, 
     timeinfo->tm_min, timeinfo->tm_sec);
OutputDebugStringW(buff);
```