# ROOT(CERN): How to draw a figure with title in unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, root-framework

I'm trying to draw a scatter figure via root-framework(cern). I want to set the titles of the figure in chinese, but I failed. My code for setting the title is

```
TGraphErrors graph(x,y,x_err,y_err);
char title[]=u8"圖表標題;x座標;y座標";//chinese title
graph.SetTitle(title);
```

But in the figure, all the titles are shown in garbled text as shown in the following picture shown:

[image: figure with garbled text]

Also, if I use a unicode string(i.e. `wchar_t title[]=L"圖表標題;x座標;y座標"`), I will get an error since `graph.SetTitle()` doesn't support that. But all strings above can show properly in the standard input/output in the terminal. So it seems that the question is not the string contains chars with wrong encoding, but root-framework can't perform them properly. Is there any way to show unicode in the figure?

p.s. I run the code by `root code.cpp` and compile it with g++, but the results are the same. My root's version is 6.26/02 and my OS version is Ubuntu 22.04.

p.s. Also, if there is a solution for both way of building the code (compiled by g++ or use as a root marco),it will be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between char\* and wchar\_t\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532785/difference-between-char-and-wchar-t)

Comment: @JosefZ I'm sorry that my expression is misleading. I've update the question. But your comment is useful. It help me clarify the problem happens in that case. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dirty hack: instead of providing Chinese characters via `TGraph::SetTitle()`, you can place `TMathText` instances wherever you want your characters to appear:

```
    gStyle->SetOptTitle(0); // no graph title please, we'll create our own

    double x1[5]{0., 1., 2., 3., 4.}, y1[5]{1., 2., 3., 4., 5.};
    TGraph* graph_one = new TGraph(5, x1, y1);
    graph_one->Draw("AP");

    (new TMathText(2.0, 5.5, "\\hbox{圖表標題}"))->Draw(); // graph title

    TMathText l_x; // x-axis title
    l_x.DrawMathText(4.0, 0.2, "\\hbox{x座標}");

    TMathText l_y; // y-axis title
    l_y.SetTextAngle(90);
    l_y.DrawMathText(-0.3, 4.5, "\\hbox{y座標}");
```

[image: example of a TGraph with Chinese characters in the TGraph title and in the axes titles]

Comment: Could I modify the font size of the text in `\hbox{}`? I tried to use LaTeX syntax such as `\hbox{\small text}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Not exactly: to increase the font size by 100%, add `l_y.SetTextSize(l_y.GetTextSize()*2.0);` after `l_y.SetTextAngle(90);`